# If value return the value. If a record not exists or when column is null, return 0 in Sql Server - different ways

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

*I want to return `0` if there is no record or if the `Column1` is null.*

```
select @var =  Column1
from myschema.mytable
where Id = @suppliedId;

select isnull(@var, 0);
```

**The above code outputs `0` if if `Column1` is null. Or if a row is not found**

Whereas I tried to save some keystrokes but it resulted in,

```
select isnull(Column1, 0)
from myschema.mytable 
where Id = @suppliedId;
```

**The above code outputs `null` if `Column1` is null or when there is no row**

Any ideas what is wrong here ? Or is there any shorter way of writing the first code ?

Comment: coalesce(column1, 0), ANSI SQL way.

Comment: @jarlh: the `coalesce` doesn't return 0 if the `Column1` is null. Just tried :(

Comment: Are you sure there is a record where ID=@suppliedID?

Comment: @roryap: there is no record ofcourse. Even when no record is found, I want to return 0 not null

Comment: Well there's your problem.  If there's no record, then there won't be a record for which to display the result of your `ISNULL` function.

Comment: @roryap: Okies. But any way to do when there is no row or when the value is null ? Like a short cut or recommended way of working like the first code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT @var = ISNULL(MAX(Column1), 0)
FROM   myschema.mytable
WHERE  Id = @suppliedId;
```

A scalar aggregate always returns a single row even if the underlying query returns zero rows.

Comment: Great one liner. Thanks

Comment: But what if you have multiple rows in the results set? It won't be correct, you will have the same result in all the rows. It works only for the case where the result set is empty

Comment: @Zsuzsa - The original query is non deterministic in that case. How would you assign multiple values to a scalar variable? The query only makes sense if there is a unique constraint on `Id ` but the value may or may not exist.

Comment: True, you are right. Also the original query would work only for 1 row

Comment: Guys, the `Id` has a primary key constraint. So, there would only be one row at a time. so, I guess Martin's Query would always work :)

Answer (score 1):

Not really saving key strokes, but something like this could help :-)

```
SELECT TOP 1 tbl.field
FROM
(
    SELECT 0 AS inx, 'no record' AS field
    --if only one row is possible, than set '1' literally
    UNION SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY mytable.orderfield), ISNULL(mytable.Land,'is null')
    FROM mytable
    WHERE IDENTITY = @suppliedID
    ) AS tbl
ORDER BY tbl.inx DESC
```

Comment: One advantage (if needed) You'll know the reason (null or "no record")... Please vote up if helfull thx